# Java Rest Best Practices

Tags: java, rest, helper

I'm new to rest webservice and have a novice q'. I've created a rest class and would like to use helper classes to handle certain operations. So for example I've created the following service:

```
   import statements...
   @Path("/UserResources")
   public class UserResource {
   //Create Spring application context
    static ClassPathXmlApplicationContext ctx = new 
    ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("classpath:/spring.xml");
    private UserResourceHelper urh = new UserResourceHelper(); // this is the helper 
    class UserProfileService userProfileService = ctx.getBean(UserProfileService.class);

    @POST
    @Path("/createUser")
    @Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public Response createUser(@Context HttpServletRequest request, Object object) { 
      StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
      User user = userProfileService.findByPrimaryKey(object); 
      sb.append(urh.createUser(object)); 
      return 
      Response.status(Status.CREATED.getStatusCode()).entity(result.toString()).build(); } }
```

I have a couple of questions on this approach:

Is this the correct way to instantiate the helper class? Or should I create a constructor and instantiate the class there? for example:

```
    public UserResource (){
     urh = new UserResourceHelper();
    }
```

On this approach will there always be a new instance of the UserResourceHelper?

If so that would mean there will not be an issue on concurrency correct? ie. 2 requests coming in at the same time and the 1st object being received by the createUser method would suddenly get replaced by the 2nd object that suddenly came in?

I'm using Hibernate for ORM. Is the way i've instantiated the entities as per my code sample correct?

Thanks for your assistance!

Comment: I see you are using spring, so you could just delegate everything to Spring instead of instantiating things by hand

Answer (score 0):

**On this approach will there always be a new instance of the UserResourceHelper?**

`yes. It always creates new instance`

**Suggestion:**

If you want to create a new service for every request, you can make this as a service instead of a helper class and you can autowire the service in the controller.

```
@Service
public class UserResourceService {

 }
```

and in the controller

```
public class someController {

    @Autowired
    private UserResourceService userResourceService;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use @Autowire annotation in spring boot, it will automatically create instance of class

```
@Autowire
UserResourceHelper userResourceHelper;
```